# How to customize the input phase of a custom field

Tags: entities

i'v created a custom field using this tutorial (http://www.slideshare.net/zugec/fields-in-core-how-to-create-a-custom-field). everything went ok and i successfully created a custom field which consists of three different text-inputs.

Now i'd like to customize the way the user inputs this field and can add another field: instead of the standard drupal visualization, i'd like to implement something like when you add your language proficency in the euroCV.eu, where each 'field' is a row and the custom inputs are cell, and when you add another field, you add another row.

i think i have to modify this hook

```
function instruction_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
  $base = $element;
  if ($instance['widget']['type'] == 'instruction_instruction_form') {
    $widget = $instance['widget'];
    $settings = $widget['settings'];

    $element['titolo_studio'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Titolo di studio'),
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['titolo_studio']) ? $items[$delta]['titolo_studio'] : NULL,
    );
    $element['descrizione'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Descrizione'),
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['descrizione']) ? $items[$delta]['descrizione'] : NULL,
    );
    $element['votazione'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Votazione'),
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['votazione']) ? $items[$delta]['votazione'] : NULL,

    );

  }
  return $element;
}
```

but i'm not sure. Is there any tutorial on this?

Comment: Translatable strings (`t('Titolo di studio')`) in the source code should always be english and then you can translate them through the UI or with a .po file because that's what Drupal assumes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a curriculum vitae type website you might want to see the [eRecruiter](http://epiqo.com/recruiter) distribution profile.

What is does is makes separate groups of fields as entities with the [Field Collection module](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection). Keep in mind that taxonomy vocabularies are fieldable in D7 so they can be attached to an entity such as a field collection. The made a module called [Term Level](http://drupal.org/project/term_level) that gives an option to add superlatives to the taxonomy terms that are just an entity in a field collection that are added to a node as a field.

It's just another way to look at the same problem.

[image]

Comment: This is very interesting, but your first link doesn't work! :)

Comment: Ok, the typo is fixed.